# Subset data by inverse pairs

Tags: r, loops, subset

The following `data.frame` should be subset by inverse pairs and a few conditions:

```
> foo
   ID Day  Period            Start              End
1  11   1 morning     Central Park Alphabet Village
2  11   1 morning     Central Park Alphabet Village
3  11   1 evening Alphabet Village        Grammercy
4  54   1 morning     Union Square        Chinatown
5  67   1 morning          Midtown           Harlem
6  67   1 morning           Harlem          Midtown
7  69   1 morning       Greenpoint Prospect Heights
8  54   1 evening        Chinatown     Union Square
9  77   1 morning       Park Slope     Williamsburg
10 73   1 evening     Williamsburg       Park Slope
11 88   2 morning        Grammercy     Battery Park
12 88   2 morning     Battery Park             SoHo
13 88   2 evening     Battery Park        Grammercy
14 69   2 evening Prospect Heights       Greenpoint
15 88   2 evening        Grammercy     Battery Park
```

For example, a `Start` and `End` station inverse pair have to fall on the 
same `Day`, have the same `ID` while the first must occur in the morning and the second in the evening.   ***EDIT:**   It should be noted that only one Start-End can be used to pair with an End-Start.  That is, once a pair is formed, the original Start-End can no longer be used to form another pair.  For example record `15` cannot be paired with record `13` because `13` is already "taken".

The output of the subset would always be an *even* number.  In this case it would be:

```
   ID Day  Period        Start          End
3  54   1 morning Union Square    Chinatown
7  54   1 evening    Chinatown Union Square
10 88   2 morning    Grammercy Battery Park
11 88   2 evening Battery Park    Grammercy
```

I am not sure if a `subset()` function should be used along with a for loop or how to structure the loop.  It should say something like - if `start` and `end` are equal to `end` and `start` of the following row and `ID` = `ID` , `Day` = `Day` and the `Period` of the first record = "morning" while the second record = "evening"

I think the code should start with something like this: `if(foo[i-1,"start"] == foo[i,"end"]) & (foo[i-1,"end"] == foo[i,"start"])` but am not sure.  The idea is to keep all inverse pairs that meet those conditions. Any guidance and explanation of steps to take would be appreciated.

The sample data:

```
> dput(foo)
structure(list(ID = c(11L, 11L, 11L, 54L, 67L, 67L, 69L, 54L, 
77L, 73L, 88L, 88L, 88L, 69L, 88L), Day = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), Period = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("evening", 
"morning"), class = "factor"), Start = structure(c(3L, 3L, 1L, 
11L, 8L, 7L, 6L, 4L, 9L, 12L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 10L, 5L), .Label = c("Alphabet Village", 
"Battery Park", "Central Park", "Chinatown", "Grammercy", "Greenpoint", 
"Harlem", "Midtown", "Park Slope", "Prospect Heights", "Union Square", 
"Williamsburg"), class = "factor"), End = structure(c(1L, 1L, 
4L, 3L, 6L, 7L, 9L, 11L, 12L, 8L, 2L, 10L, 4L, 5L, 2L), .Label = c("Alphabet Village", 
"Battery Park", "Chinatown", "Grammercy", "Greenpoint", "Harlem", 
"Midtown", "Park Slope", "Prospect Heights", "SoHo", "Union Square", 
"Williamsburg"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("ID", "Day", 
"Period", "Start", "End"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-15L))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After grouping by 'ID', 'Day', `filter` the 'Period' where the `unique` element count is greater than 1 (`ndistinct`), then change the `factor` columns to `character` and do a `filter` which matches the condition in OP's post

```
 library(dplyr)
 foo %>%
     group_by(ID, Day) %>%
     filter(n_distinct(Period)>1) %>% 
     mutate(Start = as.character(Start), End = as.character(End)) %>%
     filter(Start[1]==End[n()] & Start[n()] == End[1]) 
 #    ID   Day  Period        Start          End
 #  (int) (int)  (fctr)        (chr)        (chr)
 #1    54     1 morning Union Square    Chinatown
 #2    54     1 evening    Chinatown Union Square
 #3    88     2 morning    Grammercy Battery Park
 #4    88     2 evening Battery Park    Grammercy
```

In `dplyr` versions 0.5.0 and above, we can use `mutate_if`

```
foo %>%
   group_by(ID, Day) %>% 
   filter(n_distinct(Period)>1)  %>% 
   mutate_if(is.factor, as.character) %>%
   filter(Start[1]==End[n()] & Start[n()] == End[1]) 
#     ID   Day  Period        Start          End
#   <int> <int>   <chr>        <chr>        <chr>
#1    54     1 morning Union Square    Chinatown
#2    54     1 evening    Chinatown Union Square
#3    88     2 morning    Grammercy Battery Park
#4    88     2 evening Battery Park    Grammercy
```

Comment: thank you, although I am getting `Error in merge_args(fun$expr, list(...)) : object 'Start' not found`

Comment: @the_darkside which version of `dplyr` you have?

Comment: package version `0.5.0`

Comment: @the_darkside In that version `mutate_all`, `mutate_if` should all work,  Anyway, I changed to `mutate`

Comment: This is simple and elegant and it works.  One question: how does it take the `Period` column into account so that "morning" can only be the first part of a pair and "evening" only the second?

Comment: @the_darkside It can be done by doing an `arrange` on the 'Period'  i.e `%>% arrange(desc(Period)) %>% mutate_if(is.factor, as.character) %>%`

Comment: I just came across an error when running this code on the larger dataset as I forgot to specify one important piece of information.   Once a symmetric pair is found (A-B  B-A) , the original (A-B) cannot be used again to pair with another occurrence of (B-A).  Does that make sense?  Please see my edited question.  I appreciate your time

Comment: If I add an extra record, the last pair is not counted .  In other cases, more than one B-A is counted for one A-B.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132567/discussion-between-the-darkside-and-akrun).

Comment: @the_darkside In that case, you can try with `%>% filter(!(duplicated(Start)& duplicated(End))) %>%  filter(Start[1]==End[n()] & Start[n()] == End[1])` after the `mutate` step

Comment: Thanks @akrun.  But there is one more problem - in some cases the output will consist of an odd number of rows, which is impossible.   I have updated the table and `dput` to show how.  When I run the above code on the new data with the added record  - the `Battery Park - Soho` trip is included in the output , although it should not be.   Is there a reason why this is happening? Thanks again for your time

Comment: does that make sense?

Comment: I guess to clarify there can only be one inverse pair per ID per day, and that can only consist of two records, the first of which must be coded `morning` and the second of which must be coded `evening`.

Comment: @the_darkside Perhaps `foo %>%
   group_by(ID, Day) %>% 
   filter(n_distinct(Period)>1)  %>% 
   mutate_if(is.factor, as.character)  %>%
   mutate(indx = paste(pmin(Start, End), pmax(Start, End)))  %>%
   filter((duplicated(indx)|duplicated(indx, fromLast=TRUE))) %>%
   filter(!duplicated(Start, fromLast=TRUE)) %>%
   filter(n()==2)  %>%
   select(-indx)`

Comment: Thanks! Could you explain the last four lines of code (starting from `mutate(indx...` ?

Comment: @the_darkside In the second `mutate` we ordered the 'Start', 'End' and `paste`d to create a string column 'indx', then filter only the duplicated elements, in the second filter, remove the duplicates from 'Start' and check whether the number of rows is 2 for each group.  Please check if that works in your original dataset.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL, you would use the self join with union query. Consider the same approach in base R by splitting morning and evening subsets, then merging them on *ID*, *Day*, and *Start*, *End* (reverse pairings), finally `rbind` then back together splitting corresponding columns:

```
mdf <- setNames(df[df$Period=='morning',], paste0(colnames(df), "_m"))
edf <- setNames(df[df$Period=='evening',], paste0(colnames(df), "_e"))

rbind(setNames(merge(mdf, edf,
                    by.x=c("ID_m", "Day_m", "Start_m", "End_m"), 
                    by.y=c("ID_e", "Day_e", "End_e", "Start_e"))[colnames(mdf)], colnames(df)),
      setNames(merge(mdf, edf,
                     by.x=c("ID_m", "Day_m","Start_m", "End_m"), 
                     by.y=c("ID_e", "Day_e", "End_e", "Start_e"))[c("ID_m", "Day_m", "Period_e", "End_m", "Start_m")], colnames(df)))

#   ID Day  Period        Start          End
# 1 54   1 morning Union Square    Chinatown
# 2 88   2 morning    Grammercy Battery Park
# 3 54   1 evening    Chinatown Union Square
# 4 88   2 evening Battery Park    Grammercy
```

---

**SQL** counterpart *(works in MS Access returning exact same output)*

```sql
SELECT t1.*
FROM
   (SELECT m.ID, m.Day, m.Period, m.[Start], m.[End]
    FROM RDataSet AS m
    WHERE (((m.Period)='morning'))) As t1
INNER JOIN
   (SELECT e.ID, e.Day, e.Period, e.[Start], e.[End]
    FROM RDataSet AS e
    WHERE (((e.Period)='evening'))) As t2
ON t1.ID = t2.ID AND t1.Day = t2.Day AND t1.[Start] = t2.[End] AND t1.[End] = t2.[Start]

UNION

SELECT t2.*
FROM
   (SELECT m.ID, m.Day, m.Period, m.[Start], m.[End]
    FROM RDataSet AS m
    WHERE (((m.Period)='morning'))) As t1
INNER JOIN
   (SELECT e.ID, e.Day, e.Period, e.[Start], e.[End]
    FROM RDataSet AS e
    WHERE (((e.Period)='evening'))) As t2
ON t1.ID = t2.ID AND t1.Day = t2.Day AND t1.[Start] = t2.[End] AND t1.[End] = t2.[Start]
```

Comment: Thank you ,this is very helpful for future PostgreSQL queries

Comment: Indeed. In fact, with Postgres you can rewrite this with [CTE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/queries-with.html) to avoid the repeating text.